# Bluetooth and audio driver problem

Tags: bluetooth

I use a bluetooth headset with a bluetooth adapter from UGREEN 5.0, the first few times when I connected the headset, it showed AirPods Pro HandsFree and HeadSet, not which one I chose the AirPods Pro HeadSet where the sound quality was much better, but now HeadSet is not showing up anymore.

If I use HandsFree the sound quality is very bad, and also before there was a lot more sound codecs, and now whichever one I choose the quality is very bad, for example high fidelity playback does not appear to choose. I don't know if anyone could help me.